# Switching a value from positive to negative using binary and twos complement

Tags: python, binary, twos-complement

So for my college computing course(UK), we were assigned a homework task to change a user's input to its negative equivalent (1 to -1, 13 to -13 etc...) but I cant figure out how to do it. I've got some code I've smashed together from other pages on stackoverflow, but my outputted result always includes a 0 on the front, meaning the value isn't negative anymore. I'm unsure how to change this as when i alter my recursive code at the bottom, I get the error of:

```
File "<ipython-input-23-300b7347f10c>", line 22
    return(num % 2, end = '')
                    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax. Maybe you meant '==' or ':=' instead of '='?
```

I'm reasonably new to coding seriously, only having focused on basics back in high school so I don't really know how to solve this issue.

(Also, we were told we couldn't use any of python's inbuilt functions for converting to and from binary and denary)

```
#Outputting original binary
binary = str(input("Enter a binary number:")) #asks for the binary number
RevBinary =binary[::-1] #Reverses the number for multiplying
count = 0 #sets counter at 0
denary = 0 #sets the denary value at 0


for number in RevBinary:
  denary += 2**count*int(number) #does 2^count multiplied by whatever the number in RevBinary the for loop is currently at
  count+=1 #increases count for next number

print("The original denary number is: [", denary, "]")

#----THE PROBLEM AREA----
NewDenary = Denary + 1 

def DecimalToBinary(num):

  if num >= 1:
    DecimalToBinary(num // 2)
  print(num % 2, end = '') ####Can't edit this line else i get the error message stated above

DecimalToBinary(NewDenary)
```

Comment: Why have you put your comments in backticks? Comments should just be preceded by `#`.

Comment: The line in the error message doesn't exist in the code you posted.

Comment: `return` isn't a function call, you don't give names to the returned values. Why do you think you need to return `end=''`? That's only for printing, it's not something you need to return from a function.

Comment: You should clarify what input and output are, currently you're contradicting yourself by showing 13 as input but requesting "Enter a binary number".

Comment: @Kelly Bundy It asks for a user's inputted binary number but at the moment Im testing with 10(1010) and 11(1011)

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like the `return` statement was just a mis-pasting. If you want to build a string by recursion, you just need a plus sign between strings.

```
def decimal_to_binary(num:int):
    if num < 0:
        raise ValueError('negative numbers not supported')
    elif num > 1:
        return decimal_to_binary(num >> 1) + decimal_to_binary(num & 1)
    else:
        return '1' if (num & 1) else '0'
```

Flipping bits in a string of ones and zeros sounds like a simple list-comprehension and a string join, maybe with some padding. I'm reluctant to post what sounds like a full solution to an assignment.

Comment: Its just a fun homework task they set and they said we could use google, hence why im here so no need to worry about it being an assignment. Ive tried implementing the code posted but it doesnt end up giving the negative number but its definitely my implementation of the code. I'm still reasonably new to python so dont quite get why it isnt working